# Creating opacity mask in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat, masking, transparency-opacity

I have an NDSI snow layer loaded in Google Earth Engine. Since snow is present for values <0.4, I want to make values >0.4 opaque. I looked at the manual's examples, but this code is not giving me what I want. Instead I get black (<0.40) and white (>0.40).

What am I missing?

```js
var winter = NDSI.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(1999,2018,'year')).filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(6,8,'month'));
var medianWinter = winter.median();
var medianWinterMask = medianWinter.gt(0.4);
Map.addLayer(medianWinterMask);
```

Comment: What is it giving you?

Answer (score 3):

To mask an image, use the method [ee.Image.updateMask()](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs#eeimageupdatemask). [Masking](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/tutorial_api_05#masking) is also covered in the [Introduction to the Earth Engine JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/tutorial_api_01) tutorial.

There are many ways to present masked data, but here is one possibility using the variables from your example code:

```js
Map.addLayer(medianWinter.updateMask(medianWinterMask), {min:0, max:100});
```

Answer (score 2):

Very useful, Tyler, thanks! After looking at the documentation, I was able to apply a second mask to exclude water. So this shows snow pixels (NDSI < 0.4) over land as white – everything else is transparent, which is what I was going for. Looks great on top of the satellite imagery. I used the [Hansen dataset](https://explorer.earthengine.google.com/#detail/UMD%2Fhansen%2Fglobal_forest_change_2017_v1_5) to identify land pixels, based on the [example in Google's tutorial](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/tutorial_api_05)).

```
//Select the datamask band from the Hansen data
var datamask = Hansen.select('datamask');
// Create a binary mask. For this band, 0=No Data, 1=Land, and 2=Water
var HansenMask = datamask.eq(1);

var winter = NDSI.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(1999,2018,'year')).filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(6,8,'month'));
var medianWinter = winter.median();
var medianWinterMask = medianWinter.gt(0.4);

var doubleMask = medianWinterMask.updateMask(HansenMask);
Map.addLayer(doubleMask.updateMask(medianWinterMask));
```

This gets the job done, but there other more elegant ways of masking water, snow, and clouds – notably [Fmask](http://pythonfmask.org/en/latest/) – here are two great tutorials with useful examples:

https://medium.com/upstream/find-water-and-remove-clouds-with-fmask-on-google-earth-engine-261c090cb62d

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/302589628_Generating_a_cloud-free_homogeneous_Landsat-8_mosaic_of_Switzerland_using_Google_Earth_Engine